# How to install a python module on a windows s mode PC

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to install a pyton module on my PC which runs on Windows S mode.
Usually I would enter "pip install module_name" in the command propmt but with this OS I can't even run the command prompt.
Is there any way I can do that or I should just disable the S mode?

Comment: You need to switch out of S mode in order to use non-Microsoft store apps.

Answer (score 0):

Windows S edition is a restricted version of the Windows operating, in short, only Microsoft Store Applications can be downloaded and executed. Please see the [below](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/switching-out-of-s-mode-in-windows-4f56d9be-99ec-6983-119f-031bfb28a307#WindowsVersion=Windows_10):

> Windows 10 in S mode is designed for security and performance, exclusively running apps from the Microsoft Store. If you want to install an app that isn't available in the Microsoft Store, you'll need to switch out of S mode. Switching out of S mode is one-way. If you make the switch, you won't be able to go back to Windows 10 in S mode. There's no charge to switch out of S mode

As PIP is not available as a Windows store application at this time, you will not be able to install new packages via PIP when working within a Windows S environment